# Enums with positive and negative values

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, enums

I need to create a large enum which will be used as bit flags. Using the standard doubling i.e. 1, 2, 4 to ensure uniqueness of any combination is fine except that I run out of numbers if I use the int (2 billion upperlimit). I also cannot use a big int as Sql server has a limitation on bitwise operations and will truncate to 10 characters.

What I wanted to know is how to throw negative numbers in there as well and still ensure that all combinations remain unique. (for example some the enum values used in the ADO.NET library seem to have negative integers).

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get a bit flag functionality with negative values.

Comment: You could use 2 columns. 1 for the bit flag and the other is a bit to indicate the sign.

Comment: How many bits do you need? Do you need to process the bits in TSQL or will all of the fiddling be done in application code, e.g. C#? There is some discussion of adding UDFs to handle large binary values [here](http://www.sql-questions.com/microsoft/SQL-Server-Programming/29207417/bitwise-operation-on-binary-datatypes.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create an enum based on a `ulong` :

```
[Flags]
enum Foo : ulong
{
  A = 1 ,
  B = 2 ,
  C = 4 ,
  . . .
}
```

Store that in your database as two integers, something like this:

```
Save( Foo value )
{
  ulong bitfield = (ulong) value ;
  int hiNibble = (int)( (bitfield>>32) & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF ) ;
  int loNibble = (int)( (bitfield>>0)  & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF ) ;

  // store the hi and lo nibbles as two integer columns in your database

}
```

In your database, create the table as something like

```
create table dbo.some_table
(
  hiNibble int ,
  loNibble int ,
  bitField as convert(bigint, convert(varbinary,hiNibble) + convert(varbinary,loNibble) )
)
```

Now you have two 32-bit integers you can bit twiddle in SQL and you've got a 64-bit integer you can pass back to your C# code and rehydrate as the `ulong`-based enum it represents.